# Ubuntu 20.04 Unable to detect secondary usb display

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, usb

I have an external display that is connected to my laptop (Acer Aspire E5-575G) through USB. It was working before in windows, but not detected in Ubuntu display settings.
Current Information
sudo lshw -C display

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 620
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:136 memory:b2000000-b2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107 [GeForce 940MX]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:137 memory:b3000000-b3ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:b4080000-b40fffff
```

xranr

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1366x768      60.02*+
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

lsinput

```
/dev/input/event0
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x1
   version : 0
   name    : "Power Button"
   phys    : "PNP0C0C/button/input0"
   bits ev : (null) (null)

/dev/input/event1
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x3
   version : 0
   name    : "Sleep Button"
   phys    : "PNP0C0E/button/input0"
   bits ev : (null) (null)

/dev/input/event2
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x5
   version : 0
   name    : "Lid Switch"
   phys    : "PNP0C0D/button/input0"
   bits ev : (null) (null)

/dev/input/event3
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x1
   version : 0
   name    : "Power Button"
   phys    : "LNXPWRBN/button/input0"
   bits ev : (null) (null)

/dev/input/event4
   bustype : BUS_I8042
   vendor  : 0x1
   product : 0x1
   version : 43907
   name    : "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
   phys    : "isa0060/serio0/input0"
   bits ev : (null) (null) (null) (null) (null)

/dev/input/event5
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x0
   version : 0
   name    : "Acer WMI hotkeys"
   phys    : "wmi/input0"
   bits ev : (null) (null) (null)

/dev/input/event6
   bustype : BUS_I2C
   vendor  : 0x6cb
   product : 0x7db7
   version : 256
   name    : "SYNA7DB5:00 06CB:7DB7 Mouse"
   phys    : "i2c-SYNA7DB5:00"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : (null) (null) (null) (null)

/dev/input/event7
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x1017
   product : 0x9012
   version : 272
   name    : "SOAI USB Gaming Mouse"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : (null) (null) (null) (null)

/dev/input/event8
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x1017
   product : 0x9012
   version : 272
   name    : "SOAI USB Gaming Mouse Keyboard"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : (null) (null) (null) (null)

/dev/input/event9
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x1017
   product : 0x9012
   version : 272
   name    : "SOAI USB Gaming Mouse System Con"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : (null) (null) (null)

/dev/input/event10
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x1017
   product : 0x9012
   version : 272
   name    : "SOAI USB Gaming Mouse Consumer C"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : (null) (null) (null) (null) (null)

/dev/input/event11
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x1017
   product : 0x9012
   version : 272
   name    : "SOAI USB Gaming Mouse"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : (null) (null)

/dev/input/event12
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x1017
   product : 0x9012
   version : 272
   name    : "SOAI USB Gaming Mouse"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input1"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : (null) (null)

/dev/input/event13
   bustype : BUS_I2C
   vendor  : 0x6cb
   product : 0x7db7
   version : 256
   name    : "SYNA7DB5:00 06CB:7DB7 Touchpad"
   phys    : "i2c-SYNA7DB5:00"
   uniq    : ""
   bits ev : (null) (null) (null) (null)

/dev/input/event14
   bustype : BUS_USB
   vendor  : 0x4f2
   product : 0xb573
   version : 37377
   name    : "HD WebCam: HD WebCam"
   phys    : "usb-0000:00:14.0-7/button"
   bits ev : (null) (null)

/dev/input/event15
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x6
   version : 0
   name    : "Video Bus"
   phys    : "LNXVIDEO/video/input0"
   bits ev : (null) (null)

/dev/input/event16
   bustype : BUS_HOST
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x6
   version : 0
   name    : "Video Bus"
   phys    : "LNXVIDEO/video/input0"
   bits ev : (null) (null)

/dev/input/event17
   bustype : (null)
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x0
   version : 0
   name    : "HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone"
   phys    : "ALSA"
   bits ev : (null) (null)

/dev/input/event18
   bustype : (null)
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x0
   version : 0
   name    : "HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
   phys    : "ALSA"
   bits ev : (null) (null)

/dev/input/event19
   bustype : (null)
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x0
   version : 0
   name    : "HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
   phys    : "ALSA"
   bits ev : (null) (null)

/dev/input/event20
   bustype : (null)
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x0
   version : 0
   name    : "HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
   phys    : "ALSA"
   bits ev : (null) (null)

/dev/input/event21
   bustype : (null)
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x0
   version : 0
   name    : "HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9"
   phys    : "ALSA"
   bits ev : (null) (null)

/dev/input/event22
   bustype : (null)
   vendor  : 0x0
   product : 0x0
   version : 0
   name    : "HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10"
   phys    : "ALSA"
   bits ev : (null) (null)
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #11 (rev f1)
00:1d.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d1b (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce 940MX] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

What I have tried

1. Restarting with external screen plugged in
2. Software & updates -> changed nvidia version -> restart

Please feel free to ask for any other additional info you need! Also I am super new to Linux, any advice will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

#### @ moderators:

I use the answer format because I want to render the output from `xrandr`. (I can delete it later on,)

#### @ Detective merry

What about these lines at the end of your output from `xrandr`?

```
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

They tell me that a HDMI port and a DP port are detected. Have you connected any of them to a monitor? In that case, is the cable good?

For a comparison, I have a monitor connected via DP:

```
$ xrandr | grep connected
DVI-I-1 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 399mm
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```